# How to Update an Entity from a Thread in Dropwizard, Hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, dropwizard

I have a thread that waits until a process is complete and then needs to update an entity. But I get

> Exception in thread "Thread-22" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context

I have tried opening a new session (see the code below). Session management is normally handled by @UnitOfWork, but this annotation seems to apply only to resources.

```
public class ConfigDAO extends AbstractDAO<Config>
{
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ConfigDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
        this.sessionFactory = factory;
    }

    public Config updateFromNewSession(Config config) {
        System.out.print("current session: ");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(session);
        session.persist(config);
        session.close();
        return config;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a quick glance of the documentation will help? https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.9/docs/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods-outside-jersey-resources

Comment: The documentation states that "It will create a proxy of your class, which will open a Hibernate session with a transaction around methods with the @UnitOfWork annotation." But again this annotation only applies to resources.

Comment: And if we take a look here? https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/ce53e69d208251c157e9628ed0176c872e85af64/dropwizard-hibernate/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactoryTest.java#L59-L69

Comment: Nice, I will give that a try. Thanks for that very useful resource.

Comment: That works. thanks again